# string comparing

Tags: android

i actually i post data in php through post method and if the data is currectly send in php and i get the response and convert into String format.

The problem is that i get the response and i check the response in log cat the result is shown but when i compare those response to a string they not run.

MY CODE IS:-

```
String TAG="SUCCESS";

HttpRequest http =new HttpRequest(data1,data2,data3);
    String result = http.httpRequestPostUser(url);

    Log.d("HTTP POST RESULT FOR VALIDATION","SUCCESS"+result+"<");
    int Tag=0;

    if(TAG.equalsIgnoreCase(result)){
        System.out.println("COMPARING SUCCESS AND INCREMENT TAG");
        Tag=1;

    }
```

Comment: Is there probably any white space or newlines in `result`

Comment: try this: result.trim();

Comment: probably as result may contain spaces trim that

Answer (score 1):

check like this

```
if(result!= null && result.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(TAG))
```

and see if it is comparing

Comment: THANKS ALOT ABHINAV ITS REALY WORKING..THANKS